# Are there any recommended tools for beautifying PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, maven-2

Does anyone know of a good tool for cleaning up/formatting PHP files?  I'd need something that can handle HTML with < ?php ?> tags, as well as pure PHP files.  Ideally, I'd like a Maven mojo, since the rest of my code is being generated by Maven already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really found any completely satisfactory solution yet, but I'm comparing several options, now.  I'll be documenting my progress on my [blog, if anyone's interested in the future.](http://blog.grgcomponents.com/?p=26)

Answer (score 2):

Haven't worked with php for a while now, but I remembered using [PHP Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier)